# Django logging with dictConfig cannot find "logging" module

Tags: python, django, logging, python-2.6, django-1.3

My LOGGING directive in settings is set to:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s::(%(process)d %(thread)d)::%(module)s - %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file_handler': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter':'default',
            'class': 'logging.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename':'Project_log',
            'when':'midnight',
            'interval':1
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file_handler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

The class of the handler is set to logging.HandlerName as per the docs example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

But I receive the following error:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 776, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py",     line 575, in configure
'%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file_handler': Cannot resolve 'logging.TimedRotatingFileHandler': No module named TimedRotatingFileHandler
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to write,

```
logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
```

as the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` is part of the handlers package of logging.

Comment: I just checked in ipython which is awesome if you just need to find out what exactely you need to import

Comment: It should be `logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler`